# Search multiple shared calendars in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, search, exchange-2010

Using I'm setting up shared calendars for a department in our office.  Everyone is using Office 2010 on Exchange 2010.  Each person's calendar is shared with everyone else, and they can all book appointments for each other.

The only thing I haven't quite figured out is search.  If they want to search for an appointment, but don't know who it's booked with, they have to search each person's calendar individually by clicking on the calendar, then clicking search, and repeating for each person's calendar until they find the appointment.

Is there any way (built into outlook, addon, server side webpage, ANYTHING) that lets you search multiple shared calendars at once?

Comment: When in Calendar view, with shared calendars selected, what happens when something is entered into the search box in the upper right corner work?

Comment: It searches the currently selected shared calendar.  But not all of them.

Comment: What if multiple calendars are selected?

Comment: I dont think you actually CAN select multiple calendars at once.  ctrl clicking a second calendar just focuses on the second one.

Comment: When in calendar view I am able to check `Shared Calendars` in the navigation pane, which selects all listed under shared, then search them. Maybe it has to do with the way Exchange is set up.

Comment: When I tested that, it would only find events from one calendar.  eg. if I had events called "test a", "test b", etc on 3 different calendars and searched for "test" it would only show one of them.  But I will try again.

Comment: I can select multiple calendars in 2010, but have had no luck searching through them.

Answer (score 1):

- Left click Start
- Enter text to be searched in "Search programs and files" field box (immediately above Start button - lower left corner)  Note:  Do not hit "enter"
- Select Microsoft Outlook in results box (directly above the search field)
  This will give you EVERYTHING relating to the text you entered - look for appointment icon on the left to find the appointment you are looking for....

Comment: Sadly, some of the computers are still windows XP and lack this search feature.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it works all that well, but in Outlook 2010 client, go to File → Options → Search → Under Results, make sure "All Folders" is selected.

Comment: Does not help at all